# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: A7

Tags: java

I have a little problem. I am trying to decompress a text file but it throws out an
" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: A7".
I can't seem to figure out the issue. Thanks for the help.

```
try (
  ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(sourcefile)));
) {
  codes = (String[])objInput.readObject();
  length = objInput.readInt();
  while (true) {
    sbEncode.append(getBits(objInput.readByte())); //line43
  }
} catch (EOFException ex) {
}

sbEncode.delete(length, sbEncode.length());

StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbCharCode = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < sbEncode.length(); i++) {
  sbCharCode.append(sbEncode.charAt(i) + "");
  for (int j = 0; j < codes.length; j++) {
    if (sbCharCode.toString().equals(codes[j])) {
      sbText.append((char)j);
      sbCharCode = new StringBuilder();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: A7
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:3142)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:3176)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:3248)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3397)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:1081)
    at DecompressFile.main(DecompressFile.java:43)
```

Comment: The the most likely cause is that you have been **appending** objects to an existing object serialization file or stream.  That leads to a corrupted stream ... when you try to read it.  (The other possibility is that the file you are attempting to read is not an object serialization file at all, but that would most likely give a different exception message.)